# Customising Grub for Windows with Ubuntu 23 installed

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub

I've been trying to add a grub menu item for Windows 10 on my system. I've successfully added an entry by creating a custom menu entry but each time it fails to work - with an error that `/efi/EFI/bootmngr` is not found (for Windows)

My set up has Ubuntu installed on a USB SSD (sdb) which loads and works perfectly.

Windows is installed on an internal drive (sda)

Windows will install if I unplug the external usb drive - but not my ideal solution

I have edited `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to add the menu:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 1866-186C
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

I can see the ID of the disk from disk manager and also listing the uuid of the drives on my system

I then `sudo update-grub` to rebuild the menu and can see the entry I created but it fails

I'm unclear how to proceed and get this to work.

There are quite a few references out there which describe this process but struggling to follow and customize my menu - I've also installed grub customizer but again no difference.

Any help appreciated

(was it a good idea to install ubuntu 23 instead of 22?)

Comment: You need to be specific, there is no 22 or 23 Ubuntu. Do you mean 22.04 now .4 with 5 years of support, 3 for flavors, or 23.10  or 23.04 (EoL) which only have 9 months of support.? And are both installs UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you really need to have ESP - efi system partition on external drive. Grub Customizer can make things more difficult as it replaces grub with its own proxy files. Post this above in question: `lsblk -f`  Does Windows boot ok from UEFI boot menu? And is Windows fast startup off? Grub only boots working Windows with fast startup & bitlocker off.